# Making an array of objects Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a platformer and I have a class called Platform that takes an x position, and y position, a width, a height and a color, then sets them inside of that platform.

```
platform = new Platform(100, 250, 100, 10, Color.BLUE);
```

Like this.

I  can call the variables as such:

```
g.fillRect(platform.x, platform.y, platform.width, platform.height);
```

and when I want to get the color of the platform I do this:

```
g.setColor(platform.color);
```

I also have a player that works very similarly.

I have a collision method:

```
int LXOff = (platform.x - player.width); // boundaries
int LYOff = (platform.y - player.height); // boundaries
int RXOff = (platform.x + platform.width); // boundaries
int RYOff = (platform.y + platform.height); // boundaries

int LXOff2 = (platform2.x - player.width);
int LYOff2 = (platform2.y - player.height);
int RXOff2 = (platform2.x + platform2.width);
int RYOff2 = (platform2.y + platform2.height);
if(x <= 5 || y <= 29) // numbers are specific to the perfect border of the screen
{
    return true;
}
if(x >= 495 - player.width || y >= 495 - player.height) // numbers are specific to the perfect border of the screen
{
    return true;
}
if(x >= LXOff && y >= LYOff && x <= RXOff && y <= RYOff)
{
    return true;
}
if(x >= LXOff2 && y >= LYOff2 && x <= RXOff2 && y <= RYOff2)
{
    return true;
} 
return false;
```

My problem is that I need to create a whole extra set of variables that represent the boundaries that a second platform uses. I'm wondering that for future use if I were to use a larger amount of platforms, how would I simplify it using an array or something like that of Platforms, then I could draw all the platforms in the array using some loop.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you not know how to make an array of objects or is it something else?

Comment: I'm trying to make an array of Platforms so that I can make multiple platforms without making my code lengthy.

Comment: And what is stopping you?

Comment: I do not know how to do this exactly...

Comment: You don't know how to create an array in Java? You don't know the syntax? Seriously?

Comment: I know how to make an array, I know the syntax, but I've never dealt with arrays of objects, i'm not sure how to go about making it work.

Comment: @GrantStokes there are no arrays of objects, only arrays of object references - which work pretty much the same way as arrays of ints, or booleans, or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I believe for a platform you will use you will create a new Platform object. create a Map to create a map of platform names as key and platform objects as values. Retrieve the Platform object by the platform name when required

```
Platform android = new Platform(....);
Platform windows = new Platform(....);
Map<String, Platform> map = new HashMap<String, Platform>();
map.put("android", android);
map.put("windows", windows);

//for retrieval
map.get("android");
```

If the borders are variable the I would suggest to create an abstract class with the common logic and a platform specific class for each Platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
Platform[] platforms = new Platform[N]
```

where N is size of array.

If you do not no size of array at the moment of creation of array, you should better use

```
List<Platform>  platforms = new ArrayList<Platform>()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you have several Platforms to draw, but you also want to draw some Boundaries?  The O-O way would be to define a common interface for both.

One option would be to define an interface, perhaps **RectangleLike**, with `getX(), getWidth(), getColor()` etc...  Then you loop over a big array (note: better to use a List) of RectangleLike and call the appropriate code.

Alternatively, and, IMO better, define an interface, perhaps **CanDrawIntoGraphics**, with one method, `drawYourself(Graphics g)`.  Loop over a List of them calling `drawYourself().`

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution you have to send an arraylist of Platform

```
List <Platform> platformList =new ArrayList<Platform> ();
platformList.add(platform1);
platformList.add(platform2);
```

Send this platformList to your method than there

```
foreach(Platform platform:platformList){
    int LXOff = (platform.x - player.width);
    int LYOff = (platform.y - player.height);
    int RXOff = (platform.x + platform.width);
    int RYOff = (platform.y + platform.height);

    if(x >= LXOff && y >= LYOff && x <= RXOff && y <= RYOff)
    {
        return true;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Java docs states that

A **Collection** — sometimes called a container — is simply an object that groups multiple elements into a single unit. Collections are used to store, retrieve, manipulate, and communicate aggregate data. Typically, they represent data items that form a natural group, such as a poker hand (a collection of cards), a mail folder (a collection of letters), or a telephone directory (a mapping of names to phone numbers).

So In order to Maintain Number of Platform for future use , You can make a collection of Platform instead of Array , because Collection has the ability to expand and shrink dynamically .

Coming to Coding side either use [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) or [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of Platforms and if you want to remove duplicay Use **Set** Interface

Suppose You are having 2 Platform then you can use this

```
List<Platform> platformList=Arrays.asList(platform1,platform2);
```

To Iterate through any collection Implementation Use , Iterator Interface

For Map You can see example posted by  **@dc.sashwat**